# Как прочитать емейлы с gmail.com

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, mailkit

Задача такова:

1. Получить все емейлы с почтовика (из папки Inbox определённого аккаунта).
2. Найти нужное письмо и получить из него гиперссылку.

Так вот у меня получилось получить емейлы с помощью библиотеки MailKit, но не могу получить гиперссылку с нужного письма, как это можно сделать с помощью библиотеки MailKit.
Вот кусок кода с помощью которого получаю все нужные емейлы

```
public void GetMessages()
{
    SetUpConnection();
    var inbox = client.Inbox;
    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    var folders = client.GetFolder(client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Folder test {0}", folders.Count);
    foreach(var folder in folders.GetSubfolders())
    {
        foreach(var subFolder in folder.GetSubfolders())
        {
            if (subFolder.Name.Equals("Вся почта") || subFolder.Name.Equals("All Mail"))
            {
                subFolder.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
                for (int i = subFolder.Count - 1; i > subFolder.Count - 20; i--)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Subject: " + subFolder.GetMessage(i).Subject);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TextBody: " + subFolder.GetMessage(i).TextBody);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж у тебя есть тело имейла, то есть текст... То ты по нему можешь найти регулярным выражением все ссылки в тексте.

Я нагуглит такую вот регулярочку универсальную:

```
^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$
```

Она стремная, но соберет любого рода ссылки, хттп, хттпс, фтп и т.д.

Будет как-то так:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$");
Match match = regex.Match(emailBody);
```

PS: По каким именно признакам отличить нужное писмо от ненужных я не подскажу ибо не оракул)

Comment: Я имел ввииду немного другую ссылку, мне необходимо получить ссылку которая зашита в ту ссылку которая приходит на емейл. Я читал то вроде бы можно парсить это в Html текст, а потом каким то образом получить значение аттрибута, но ни как не мог найти рабочий пример.

Comment: ну тогда путь или тот же что я дал выше (только закыдываешь хтмл текст) или качаешь htmlAgrilityPack, загружаешь хтмл туда и ищешь ноду <a> с атрибутом href и вытягиваешь ссылку.

Comment: Так вот а как мне получить этот хтмл текст?

Comment: @MainStar Логически подумайте. У вас есть строка `subFolder.GetMessage(i).TextBody`, что делает тут `TextBody` и что надо заместо него поставить?

Comment: С мейлКит-ом не работал. Но гугл говорит про пропертю HtmlBody. А так же вот этот код ```var body = message.BodyParts.OfType ().FirstOrDefault (x => x.ContentType.Matches ("text", "html"));```. Но лучше использовать пропертю, если ее найдешь :D

Comment: Кстати, вариант через регулярки тоже должен подойти, не знаю что автору не понравилось... Вот допустим если смотреть на письмо через `TextBody`, все ссылки на [месте](https://hastebin.com/etakogaxex.rb), только они тут через свой тег (`текст<ссылка>`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо, не подумал сразу о том, что бы заменить TextBody на  HtmlBody, сейчас все работает, спасибо!

Comment: на забывай голосовать/отмечать вопросы как полезные/решившие проблему :)